# How to call a javascript function from <td> element inside ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

call angular function inside ng-repeat td . Take the value from td and replace it from the function value.The below code is not working. The same getCSTDateTime is coming in the table instead of date.I want to convert system date to cst date .
For Example:

```
<td id="txt">{{getCSTDateTime(document.lastUpdateDateTime)}}</td>

</tr>
```

I have searched in stack over flow and followed the above steps. And added this function to $Scope as well. But still this function is not calling and returning my value.

```
$scope.getCSTDateTime = getCSTDateTime;



 $scope.getCSTDateTime= function(lastUpdateDateTime) {
      var currentDate =lastUpdateDateTime;
      var cstDate;
      var hour;
      var minutes;
      var seconds;
      var jan = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
      var jul = new Date(currentDate.getFullYear(), 6, 1);

      var  timezoneOffset =Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());

      // Check if daylight savings
      if (currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() < timezoneOffset) {
          // Adjust date by 5 hours
          cstDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime()-((1 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * 5));
        }
      else {
          // Adjust date by 6 hours
             cstDate = new Date(currentDate.getTime() - ((1 * 60 * 60 * 1000) * 6));
      }           
      hour = cstDate.getHours();
      minutes = cstDate.getMinutes();
      seconds = cstDate.getSeconds();
      m = checkTime(minutes);
      s = checkTime(seconds);
      //date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma" :'CDT'
      var month = cstDate.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
      var day = cstDate.getUTCDate();
      var year = cstDate.getUTCFullYear();
      document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =      month + "/" + day + "/" +year +" "+h+":"+m;
};



    //var Date.prototype.stdTimezoneOffset = $( function () {

// var jan = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 0, 1);
       // var jul = new Date(this.getFullYear(), 6, 1);
      //  return Math.max(jan.getTimezoneOffset(), jul.getTimezoneOffset());
    //});

    //Date.prototype.isDstObserved = function () {
       // return this.getTimezoneOffset() < this.stdTimezoneOffset();
    //}


var checkTime=$(function checkTime(i) {
      if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
      return i;
    });
```

I want this function to be called which is defined inside my controller

Comment: Your function doesn't expect any parameter and doesn't return anything, that's propably why it doesn't work. `document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML` shouldn't be used in angularjs and seems that you're creating multiple `td`s with `id="row"` - this won't work too

Comment: Okay instead what we need to do?? Please suggest me the solution.

Comment: Here i need to take the value from td and update that value in the same td. This is my requirement here. Hope you all understood. Please provide me solution.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the same datetime is that you are not using the lastUpdateDateTime that is being passed from the function call.

```
 {{ getCSTDateTime(document.lastUpdateDateTime)}}

$scope.getCSTDateTime= function() {....
```

You need to act on the argument that is passed to the function

```
$scope.getCSTDateTime= function(lastUpdateDateTime) {.... get date calculations....
```

The calculations you do on that date / time should then be returned to the td to be interpolated.

And as noted - changing the innerHTML of the #txt is not very angular - you should be altering the value by altering the data passed to the model behind so that the DOM can be updated when the data changes.

Comment: Even after passing the parameter i am getting the same.Updating the question.

Answer (score 0):

change this line:

```
document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML = month + "/" + day + "/" +year +" "+h+":"+m;
```

to:

```
return month + "/" + day + "/" +year +" "+h+":"+m;
```

your interpolation directive {{}} is removed by the .innerHTML as soon as the method gets called first time and it will never update further.

Comment: it is working. Thank you. I have another blocker here. I want to pass the date from the td element to the function<td>{{getCSTDateTime(document.lastUpdateDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma")}}</td>Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '|' is unexpected, expecting [)] at column 43 of the expression [getCSTDateTime(document.lastUpdateDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma")] starting at [| date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma")]. i want to pass the date to the function in this format so that only i can able to convert to cst timing from this timing.

Comment: document.lastUpdateDateTime | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma" wouldn't do what u r trying to, change format inside the method not in html. The filter is not intended for passing arguments to function.

Comment: <td>{{getCSTDateTime(capture.lastUpdateDateTime) | date:"MM/dd/yyyy h:mma"}}</td> it worked for me after i modified. and in method i return cst date instead of return return month + "/" + day + "/" +year +" "+h+":"+m; i changed it to return cstDate; is ther any thing in angular which will give me cst date for the given date??

Comment: yes this would work and method called as usual and then filter is applied....pls check momentjs